# What should I do if my advisor is replacing me with younger, more energetic masters students?

Tags: advisor

I was working on a project with my PhD advisor that was going kind of slowly.  Now he has hired two masters students to "help" me.  They are better at coding than me and seem a lot more interested in and involved with the project than I am.  What should I do?  This is my only project with my advisor and I think he doesn't think I'm very smart.

Comment: Is your work clearly divided?

Comment: Step up to the plate and show that you can do it.

Comment: It's your only project (AKA PhD thesis) and you're not the most interested in it???

Comment: Kind of a fundamental question here: are you not interested in the project because it was assigned to you and it's not quite something in your area of interest, or is it general PhD ennui?

Comment: @Earthliŋ No I think he expects us to divide the work among ourselves.

Comment: @Broklynite It's partially because I'm taking a lot of classes and partially because I just don't like the project all that much and I'm skeptical of my advisor's approach to it.

Comment: **It's your PhD.  You have to hunt it down and kill it.**  If you don't like the project and/or you don't think the project will succeed, drop it and start another one.  If your advisor doesn't want you to "let" you drop it, find another advisor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is time to decide whether to lead or get out of the way. If you choose to get out of the way, you will need to either find a PhD project that does interest you or do something else.

The more interesting and constructive option is to decide to lead. You have presumably spent some time learning the background to the project. The new students do not have that background, but are interested in the project. You should do everything you can to help them succeed. Work with them on deciding what should be coded, bringing your background knowledge to the table. Work with them on turning results into papers. You don't have to code better than them, just make their coding more effective than it would have been without your efforts.

Comment: This is curious: how could you have answered given that the question has been put on hold two hours ago? Should we report a bug?

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano Maybe a bug. I started writing the answer several hours ago. I finished and posted it a few minutes ago, and forgot to recheck the question so I did not know it had been closed.

Comment: So probably if one drafts an answer before a question is put on hold, the system won't reject it. Good to know, let's call it a feature ;-)

Comment: I vaguely recall a similar issue on a meta somewhere - there is a window of time built in to the system to account for connectivity issues. Using it to 'get around' a hold was considered a small price to pay versus your half-finished answer disappearing when your wifi glitches.

Answer (score 12):

> I think he doesn't think I'm very smart.

More probaby, instead, he just thinks that you're not enough committed to your project. In fact, you write (bold mine):

> They are better at coding than me and **seem a lot more interested in and involved with the project than I am**.

You are a PhD student and this is your project, and you should be the one who boosts the project with work, ideas and enthusiasm: how come that these two students seem *a lot more interested in and involved with the project than you*?!

So, take the bull by the horns and be the booster of your project. Otherwise, it's time you rethink about your motivation in doing a PhD, about your interest in this specific project, and about your future goals. And talk to your advisor.